# xml version of iconifiedByDefault ignored

Tags: android, android-layout, searchview

Why is the line `android:iconifiedByDefault="false”` always ignored, requiring me to always have to find a way to do it automatically? If it’s always going to be ignored, why include it as an option? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you using the standard `SearchView`, or the v7 appcompat version? How and where are you including it in your layout?

Comment: Your questions imply that these differences matter. If so I would like to know why and how. (Presently I am using v7. and the SearchView is a view inside a relativeLayout)

Comment: The v7 `SearchView` is going to use the `iconifiedByDefault` attribute defined in your app's namespace, not in `android`. That is, if your app's namespace in the XML is like: `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`, you need to use `app:iconifiedByDefault="false”`. The "how and where" question was just to determine if you had it in a menu. I'll post an example when I get a chance, here in a minute.

Comment: heh heh. What do you know? It works. Thanks, man. I have always wondered about this and finally decided to ask. Thanks. If you don't mind I would like to mark the thread as answered if you would post as a response. No one here seems to have given this answer before.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sure, gimme a little bit. I got sidetracked earlier; forgot about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like most of the `View`s in the support libraries, the v7 appcompat `SearchView` uses attributes specific to it that are defined in the app's namespace, rather than the system namespace. This ensures that the attributes can be used in all Android versions that the library supports.

You just need to use your app's namespace prefix on the `iconifiedByDefault` attribute. For example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        ...
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: great answer: check + 1